# Oracle decode using partial string of codeset value

Tags: oracle, decode, substr

I need a code that will let me match a partial string of a school name `gr.schoolname` to `c.displayvalue` of our codeset `PSSDPriorSchools`.  The `gr.schoolname` is just the school name, the `PSSDPriorSchools` is the school name with the (school division) following it.
I need to match the `gr.schoolname` to the `c.displayvalue` of the `PSSDPriorSchools` to be able to retrieve the c.code that corresponds with the `c.displayvalue`.

```sql
Select
s.ID as ID,s.LASTFIRST as LASTFIRST,s.STUDENT_NUMBER as STUDENT_NUMBER,
decode(upper(gr.schoolname), c.code, c.displayvalue) as credit_schools
from 
                     STUDENTS s,
                     codeset c,
                     storedgrades gr
where
                     gr.schoolname= C.displayvalue
                     and c.codetype = 'PSSD_PriorSchools'
                     and gr.studentid=s.id
```

BUT our `gr.schoolname` only contains the first part of the string of `c.displayvalue`.

For example if I need to decode Pilot Mound School to a `c.code` number of 1301.

In our code set the `displayvalue` of this school contains a school division at the end like this:

```
Pilot Mound School (PRAIRIE SPIRIT SCHOOL DIVISION).
```

So I need a code that would do this:

```sql
Select
s.ID as ID,s.LASTFIRST as LASTFIRST,s.STUDENT_NUMBER as STUDENT_NUMBER,
decode(upper(***( gr.schoolname= text before the first ' (') of c.displayvalue)***, c.code,     c.displayvalue) as credit_schools
where
                      gr.schoolname= C.displayvalue
                      and c.codetype = 'PSSD_PriorSchools'
                      and gr.studentid=s.id
```

I tried it as `decode(gr.schoolname,(SUBSTR(gr.schoolname, 0, INSTR(c.displayvalue, '(')-1)),c.code,c.displayvalue)`
but I can not get it to work.

PSSDPriorSchools looks like:

| Code | Display Value | Description Reported Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Harrow School (WINNIPEG SCHOOL DIVISION) | 1001 |
| 1002 | Educational Support Services (ST. JAMES-ASSINIBOIA SCHOOL DIVISION) | 1002 |
| 1003 | Woodland Colony School (PORTAGE LA PRAIRIE SCHOOL DIVISION) | 1003 |
| 1006 | Mafeking School (SWAN VALLEY SCHOOL DIVISION) | 1006 |
| 1007 | George Fitton School (BRANDON SCHOOL DIVISION) | 1007 |

and I need to decode the `Schoolname` to match the `c.displayvalue` so I can get the c.code

| Id | LastfirstAscending | Student Number | Schoolname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2986 | Abellera, Ana Carissa Evangelista | 12945 | St. Claude School Complex |
| 2987 | Abellera, John Allen Evangelista | 12947 | Prairie Mountain High School |

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data that is representative of the problem; an explanation of the sample data and the relationships you wish to use in the query; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: You say that "our gr.schoolname only contains the first part of the string of c.display value" however, in the `WHERE` clause you specify the join condition (note: you should use ISO joins rather than legacy comma joins) is `gr.schoolname= C.displayvalue` so there cannot be a partial match unless the join condition is incorrect.

Comment: Your school names have no relationship to the display values in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

> our gr.schoolname only contains the first part of the string of c.display value.

Then the join condition `gr.schoolname= C.displayvalue` will never match the rows as they are not equal. You appear to need to join the tables on the start of the string and not on the entire string; something like:

```sql
Select s.ID,
       s.LASTFIRST,
       s.STUDENT_NUMBER,
       decode(
         gr.school_name,
         'Pilot Mound School', 1301
       ) as credit_schools
from   codeset c
       INNER JOIN storedgrades gr
       ON C.displayvalue LIKE gr.schoolname || '%'
       INNER JOIN STUDENTS s
       ON gr.studentid = s.id
where  c.codetype = 'PSSD_PriorSchools'
```

Comment: We have over 300 schools listed that need to decode, we can not put in a decode for each one as the list grows daily.

Comment: @user3380817 [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74227448/edit) to give us a complete [MRE] with sample data and an explanation of the expected output for that sample data. We do **NOT** currently have your data and you have not previously mentioned these 300 schools in your question so how are we supposed to know about them?

Comment: Sorry, I am absolutely new to oracle and coding and am struggling through this.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work either

Comment: Select s.ID,
       s.LASTFIRST,
       s.STUDENT_NUMBER,
       decode(upper(gr.schoolname), c.code, c.displayvalue)
    from   codeset c,
        students s,
       storedgrades gr
       
    where  c.codetype = 'PSSD_PriorSchools' 
    and gr.studentid=s.id and
    substr(to_char(c.displayvalue), 1, instr(to_char(c.displayvalue), ' (') 
 -1)=upper(gr.schoolname

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work.

```
Select s.ID,
       s.LASTFIRST,
       gr.schoolname,
       c.displayvalue,

  decode(c.displayvalue, c.displayvalue, c.code) as decoded_school

from   

        students s,
        storedgrades gr
-- this code next line is supposed to join gr.schoolname to any c.displayvalue that has gr.schoolname in it
left join codeset c on to_char(upper(gr.schoolname)) LIKE (upper(NVL(SUBSTR(c.displayvalue, 0, INSTR(c.displayvalue, '(')-1), c.displayvalue)) || '%')
--left join codeset c on upper(gr.schoolname) LIKE ('%' || upper(c.displayvalue) || '%')      
where  
c.codetype = 'PSSD_PriorSchools' and
gr.studentid=s.id

group by
s.ID,
       s.LASTFIRST,
      
       gr.schoolname,
       c.code,
       c.displayvalue
```

which lets me match by gr.schoolname to the c.displayvalue then decode to get my school code c.code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Pxl.png)